# Firing this function onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, midi

i have this code:
The question is:
How can i fire this code onClick instead?

JS:

```
 $("input[type=radio],button").each(function () {
        var outputName = $(this).attr("data-midioutput");
        if (outputName) {
            var output = MidiUtil.getOutput(outputName);
            if (output) {
                var outputName = $(this).attr("data-midioutput");
                var midiChannel = $(this).attr("data-midichannel");
                if (!midiChannel)
                    midiChannel = 0;

                var cc = $(this).attr("data-midicc");
                var midiValue = $(this).attr("data-midivalue");

                if (outputName && cc) {
                    var output = MidiUtil.getOutput(outputName);
                    if (output) {

                        if ($(this).attr("type") == "number") {
                            this.oninput = function () {
                                    output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), $(this).val()]);

                            };
                            //Send initial value
                                output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), $(this).val()]);
                        }
                        else { //button
                            this.onclick = function () {
                                    output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), parseInt(midiValue, 10)]);
                            };
                        }

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else {

        }

    });
```

Which is automatically fired by buttons like this:
HTML:

```
<button class="1" data-midicc="19" data-midivalue="0" data-midichannel="00" data-midioutput="IAC 1" />
```

The question is:

How can i fire this code onClick instead?
Thanks!

Comment: change your .each to .click

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the 'Jquery-each' statement to click event binding works for you well.

```
$("input[type=radio],button").on('click',function () {
        var outputName = $(this).attr("data-midioutput");
        if (outputName) {
            var output = MidiUtil.getOutput(outputName);
            if (output) {
                var outputName = $(this).attr("data-midioutput");
                var midiChannel = $(this).attr("data-midichannel");
                if (!midiChannel)
                    midiChannel = 0;

                var cc = $(this).attr("data-midicc");
                var midiValue = $(this).attr("data-midivalue");

                if (outputName && cc) {
                    var output = MidiUtil.getOutput(outputName);
                    if (output) {

                        if ($(this).attr("type") == "number") {
                            this.oninput = function () {
                                    output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), $(this).val()]);

                            };
                            //Send initial value
                                output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), $(this).val()]);
                        }
                        else { //button
                            this.onclick = function () {
                                    output.send([MidiUtil.eventTypes.MIDI_CC_CH1 + parseInt(midiChannel, 10), parseInt(cc, 10), parseInt(midiValue, 10)]);
                            };
                        }

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else {

        }
})
```

Comment: Thank you all. What i really needed was to have the "onclick" in the html form, and the js function free from onclick statements, just a function, launched by the button's onclick.